# Eliminating mysterious margin in Chrome

Tags: html, css

Please, consider the following jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/mark69_fnd/5fANH/

Here is how it looks on IE9, FF and Chrome:

IE9:
[image]

FF:
[image]

Chrome:
[image]

Please, notice the mysterious bottom yellow margin/padding found only on Chrome. WTF ???

Also note, that I link the YUI's reset CSS, so all the browsers should have been normalized.

How do I eliminate this mysterious margin/padding ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to me that the problem is white spaces, after I removed them the space is gone http://jsfiddle.net/5fANH/2/ Its the white spaces after the inputs.

Comment: Damn, I do not think I would have ever thought about it!